# Row-wrap center align in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Currently I am trying to get my columns to center using flexbox but it is sticking to the left when I resize the browser. I have tried justify content center and align-items center but I may not be putting them in the right places.  If anyone knows how to fix this that would be much appreciated! Thank you!

```css
.wrap{
 display:flex;
}

main{
 flex:1;
 display:flex;
}

aside, article{
    padding:2em; 
}

aside{
 flex:1;
}

article{
 flex:1;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  main {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <main>
        <aside>
            <h1>Do You Want to...</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>Rebrand myself online</li>
                <li>Take my current website and make it modern</li>
                <li>Find a way to make information more accessible for customers</li>
                <li> Improve customer service</li>
                <li> Reach a wider range of people</li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        <article>
            <h1>Do You Want to...</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>Create forms and documents that customers can fill out online</li>
                <li>Start an email list for recurring customers</li>
                <li>Show relatability with my audience</li>
                <li> Have 24/7 online exposure</li>
                <li>Create a map or a way for customers to find my location</li>
            </ul>
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For centering the stacked columns on the mobile view use `align-items: center` on `main`.  For the desktop view, you can collapse the columns by specifying `flex: 0 auto`.  This indicates that the item should not be allowed to grow and should use an automatic width.  Then you add `justify-content: center` to `main` to center the collapsed columns.

```css
.wrap{
 display:flex;
 
}

main{
 flex:1;
 display:flex;
 justify-content: center;
}

aside, article{

padding:2em; 
}

aside{
 flex:0 auto;
}

article{
 flex:0 auto;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  main {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<main>
<aside>
 <h1>Do You Want to...</h1>
    <ul>
  <li>Rebrand myself online</li>
  <li>Take my current website and make it modern</li>
  <li>Find a way to make information more accessible for customers</li>
  <li> Improve customer service</li>
  <li> Reach a wider range of people</li>
</ul>
</aside>
<article>
<h1>Do You Want to...</h1>

<ul>
  <li>Create forms and documents that customers can fill out online</li>
  <li>Start an email list for recurring customers</li>
  <li>Show relatability with my audience</li>
  <li> Have 24/7 online exposure</li>
  <li>Create a map or a way for customers to find my location</li>
</ul>
</article>

</main>
</div>
```

Comment: yes that does solve half the problem! Thank you! I know I may have explained it a bit confusing so I'll try again. I want the columns to move together when I resize the browser and stay in the center of page right now the left column sticks to the left side of the page and the right column moves way over to the right. Does that make anymore sense?

Comment: @Cakers So you want the columns to collapse and center at the desktop view?  I've edited my answer.  Is that closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I wanted!! Thank you so so much for helping me figure this out! You are much appreciated!